# $p$ smallest prime dividing $G$ subgroup with index $p$ normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am struggling to understand this proof.

Suppose that $p$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$ show that any subgroup of index $p$ is normal in $G$.

Proof

Let $\phi \rightarrow S_p$ be the homomorphism given by the generalized Cayley theorem. We claim $ker(\phi)=H$ which implies $H$ is normal. By first isomorphism theorem $|G/Ker \phi|$ divides $|S_p|=p!$ON the other hand $|G/Ker \phi|$ divides $|G|$ by lagrange's theorem. Since $ker\phi \leq H$ and $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $|G|$, $ker\phi=H$. I am struggling to understand this if anyone could help explain this?

Comment: What "this" are you struggling to understand? There are five sentences; which ones do you understand or not understand?

Comment: The [most easily found generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem#More_general_statement_of_the_theorem) of the Cayley theorem seems unlikely to be what you mean.  Perhaps you should recite that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually detail your difficulties, so here's a description based on a guess...

> $|G / \ker \phi|$ divides $|S_p| = p!$

means the factorization of $|G / \ker \phi|$ uses only powers of primes in the list $1, 2, \dots, p$.

> $|G / \ker \phi|$ divides $|G|$

means the factorization of $|G / \ker \phi|$ uses only power of primes listed in the factorization of $|G|$, the smallest of which is $p$.

The only prime on both lists is $p$.

Going back to the first quote, this says the index of $H$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p$.  Going back to the second quote, this says the index of $H$ in $G$ is a divisor of $p$.  So the index of $H$ in $G$ is $p$.

Comment: We're _given_ that the index of $H$ is $p$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster : "You don't actually detail your difficulties, so here's a description based on a guess..."  Interesting that the only thing you read was the last sentence.

Comment: It looks like you maybe meant that the index of $\rm{ker}\phi$ is $p$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster : Maybe.  But OP still hasn't given any hint about what he does or doesn't understand, so there is no coherent way to respond to the Question.

Comment: I fully agree.  We are left having to explain the whole proof.